# Rails 5 - Acts as Taggable On - how do I add the tag from a form selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, acts-as-taggable-on

My Proposal.rb has:

```
class Proposal < ApplicationRecord include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries

  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :randd_maturities, :randd_fields, :randd_purposes, :randd_activities
```

My proposal form.html.erb has:

```
<%= f.collection_select :randd_field_list, Randd::Field.order(:title), :id, :title, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

My proposal controller whitelists the randd_field_list with:

```
  def proposal_params
      params.require(:proposal).permit(:title,  randd_maturities_list: [], randd_field_list: [], randd_purposes_list: [],   randd_activities_list: [],
```

When I try selecting a tag from my form, I get no errors but the tag doesnt save to the proposal:

```
Processing by ProposalsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MO4g02iQgHALwVGBgVp7UN9MQvRa5uaJ56e7/tV3TTqk2UW40CLfEdrJCgafFsBNSuZEoEApXHRl3xp0zmo7Iw==", "proposal"=>{"title"=>"asdf",  "randd_field_list"=>["", "1"]
```

How do I get the form selection title to save as the tag for that proposal?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code.

Add only this line in your model.

```
 acts_as_taggable_on :randd_maturities, :randd_fields, :randd_purposes, :randd_activities
```

Add this to your controller

```
    params.require(:proposal).permit(:title,  :randd_maturities_list, 
:randd_field_list, :randd_purposes_list,   :randd_activities_list)
```

Add this to your form. My code is for simple_form_for

```
 <%= f.input :randd_maturities_list %>
```

If you are using form for use this.

```
<%= f.text_field :randd_maturities_list %>
```

Comment: HI Neeraj. I'm really not sure about whether the tags inclusion on the model is or isn't required. I've asked several quuestions trying to get an answer to that, but i can't use the gem at all if the line isn't there so I need to leave it for now. The params need to be the way I have set them out in the post, so that an array of tags can be saved - I think. I have a collection select in my form so that the only tags avaialle are those predefined/ Im struggling to get the selection to save to the list